# Undeletion request, question deleted by user after receiving an answer

Tags: discussion, support, undelete-request

I answered this question yesterday, [Can Zarya block Tracer's ultimate after being stuck?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334468/can-zarya-block-tracers-ultimate-after-being-stuck), which was then deleted by its owner. I can't see any reason why it might've been deleted, and it seems a reasonable enough question to ask, so I'd like to see it undeleted.

Is it appropriate to ask for a valid question to be undeleted if it was deleted by its owner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree this post is useful and so I've gone ahead and undeleted it.

In general if a question has merit and gets a helpful answer then the OP shouldn't be deleting it unless they have a very good reason (a single downvote doesn't qualify). The system would normally prevent this, but since the OP deleted their question so quickly after your answer it  never got an upvote, which allowed the OP to proceed with a deletion.

Comment: There's a way to have your account unassociated from a question you asked if it should live but you don't want the credit for any reason. You'd need to get in touch with the community team.

Answer (score -3):

I think that a better way of handling this would be to post a new question.

Advantages:

1. Doesn't conflict with the poster's desire to delete the poster's question.
2. You can ensure that you will follow up on edits, accepting an answer, etc.
3. This requires no moderator or community intervention.  You can just do it.

If you already wrote an answer, you can self-answer the question.